# Item-level Security on SSRS report from SharePoint list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, security, reporting-services

We have created an SSRS report from SharePoint 2010 list. We have item level permission in the source list, so the user can view only the items for which they have privilege. But in SSRS report it picks all records without filtering out using access privilege.

Is there any option in SSRS to filtering out data using access privilege of current user? If not could you explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the SSRS report running via stored credentials. If so, it's connecting via the list with that account, not as the user.

Comment: Is there option to connect SSRS using current user credentials from sharepoint?

Comment: That's one of the options in the data source, but as always, specifying that the current user should be used means that other features, such as subscriptions and snapshots won't work.

Comment: Thanks. We can set "use current windows user" in credential section of data source property.